# Traversal in html dom with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a basic query . Here is the portion of code.

```
<div id = "something">

<span class = "class1">...</span>
...
...
...
<span class = "class5"> ...</span>


</div>
```

now if i query on div id ="something" like this

```
$( "#something").children(".class5").html("response");
```

i guess it must change the html content of span with class5 ..but actually its not happening , so any help would be of immense help.Thank you

Comment: Are those spans **immediate** children of the div?

Comment: Your code works. http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/BduwU/

Comment: @elclanrs  yes,they are

Comment: Then problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: @elclanrs  but my div id is numeric

Comment: put your code in fiddle and than check it out

Comment: than show your orignal code with numeric id div

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$("#something").find("span.class5").html("response");

                     or

$("#something").find("span.class5").val("response");
```

If failed for the above code too, then do check the Error Console for any error. 
If you found any error then please mention what the error is.

Thanks,